# Debug mode in eclipse does skips break point and executes program instead

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Few days ago my Eclipse stopped running in debug mode. It does not stop at breakpoints, it does not offer me to switch to debug perspective and if I switch by myself it does not show the value of any of the variables or anything else. When it gets my input from the console it calculates an output and executes the program. It happened to other programs I tried to debug. It does not give an error but it makes it difficult where my logic faults without debug mode. Any suggestions?[image]

[image: this is what happens with the new workspace]

Comment: What errors are you facing ? Can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: How are you running the application?  If you right-click in the code editor and select "Debug As" and then "Java Application", it should launch it in debug mode.